# Require custom key to register in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

The current application I am working on requires that users can only register if they were given a registration key. In Laravel 5, I can put this in the Validator:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    // some validation fields...
    'registration_key' => 'required|same:'.$registration_key
]);
```

Which will require the `registration_key` field to be the same as the variable `$registration_key`. However, upon entering the wrong key, the error message to the view displays the key:

**Error: The registration key and [value of key] must match.**

Obviously, I don't want to display the key to the user. I know Laravel has some documentation to show how to extend the Validator facade but it is poorly explained and I can't figure it out. Has anyone done something similar and can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Validator::make($data, [
        // some validation fields...
        'registration_key' => 'required|same:' . $registration_key
    ], [
        'registration_key.same' => 'your text for the error message'
    ]);
```

I don't know if you can declare your own error messages in the Request Class but you can check it in the Controller and then add the error message.

For more information check: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages

UPDATE:

Thanks to Josh Janusch for an easier solution

```
class MyRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $registration_key = 'your key';
        return [
            'registration_key' => 'required|same:'.$registration_key
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Set custom messages for validator errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return ['registration_key.same' => 'your key is not listed'];
    }
}
```

Comment: To expand on your first sentence, to do it in a Request class, simply override the method `messages()` (or `attributes()`, if that is all you needed). They can also do `registration_key.same` as the rule name if they plan to use the `same` rule for multiple fields.

Comment: I'm out at lunch I'll check the answer in an hour. @Josh thanks for expanding on the solution

Comment: The validator is built in the Auth controller, not in a Request subclass, so how would I implement this?

Comment: in this case use my first solution: you set a third argument to the Validator::make method where you owerwrite the same error message.

Comment: Duh, forgot about that. Thank you